# I need some simple logic/programming exercises for a junior programmer

Tags: javascript

I'm currently teaching an employee ECMA script as it is needed in maintaining a workflow system we use and i need some challenges to use as exercises.

We have covered most of the language and he is now pretty familiar with the syntax so i just need him to get using it. I need to provide him exercises which make him think logically.

For example, he understands what an `if` and a `switch` is but a little unsure when to use one over the other. I just need to give him some exercises to let him have a go at working out a solution, then i'll sit with him, review his code and give advice.

Basically he just needs practice now. Is there any online resources which can give me a list of stuff to do? I found a few and we've worked through them (i.e. 99 bottles of beer, etc). We need some more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably find suitable exercises on the [Coding Kata](http://codingkata.org/) sites.
Otherwise maybe check out a book with exercises in it.

Comment: this site returns application error

Comment: http://codingkata.net/ or http://codekata.pragprog.com/

Answer (score 7):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is always a good challenge/exercise for everyone.